# Comparing two pandas series for floating point near-equality?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point, equality

I can compare two Pandas series for exact equality using `pandas.Series.equals`.  Is there a corresponding function or parameter that will check if the elements are equal to some ε of precision?

Comment: --> [`np.allclose(s1, s2)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) Set the threshold parameters, the docs explain it well.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, perfect.  Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: and use `np.isclose()` to return an element-wise boolean series

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html):

> ```
> numpy.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=False)
> ```
>
> Returns `True` if two arrays are element-wise equal within a tolerance.
>
> The tolerance values are positive, typically very small numbers. The
>   relative difference (`rtol * abs(b)`) and the absolute difference `atol`
>   are added together to compare against the absolute difference between
>   `a` and `b`.

`numpy` works well with `pandas.Series` objects, so if you have two of them - `s1` and `s2`, you can simply do:

```
np.allclose(s1, s2, atol=...)
```

Where `atol` is your *tolerance value*.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy works well with pandas Series. However one has to be careful with the order of indices (or columns and indices for pandas DataFrame)

For example

```
series_1 = pd.Series(data=[0,1], index=['a','b'])
series_2 = pd.Series(data=[1,0], index=['b','a']) 
np.allclose(series_1,series_2)
```

will return False

A workaround is to use the index of one pandas series

```
np.allclose(series_1, series_2.loc[series_1.index])
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: I'm posting this mostly because I came to this thread via a Google search of something similar and it seemed too long for a comment. Not necessarily the best solution nor strictly "ε of precision"-based, but an alternative using scaling and rounding if you want to do this for vectors (i.e. rows) rather than scalars for a `DataFrame` (rather than `Series`) without looping through explicitly:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

Xcomb = pd.concat((X, X2), axis=0, ignore_index=True)
# scale
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(Xcomb)
Xscl = scaler.transform(Xcomb)
# round
df_scl = pd.DataFrame(np.round(Xscl, decimals=8), columns=X.columns)
# post-processing
n_uniq = df_scl.drop_duplicates().shape[0]
n_dup = df.shape[0] + df2.shape[0] - n_uniq
print(f"Number of shared rows: {n_dup}")
```

Comment: You should drop duplicates within X and X2 before concatenating them

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid numpy, there is another way, use assert_series_equal

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([1.333333, 1.666666])
s2 = pd.Series([1.333, 1.666])

from pandas.testing import assert_series_equal
assert_series_equal(s1,s2)
```

raises an `AssertionError`. So use the `check_less_precise` flag

```
assert_series_equal(s1,s2, check_less_precise= True)  # No assertion error
```

This doesn't raise an `AssertionError` as `check_less_precise` only compares 3 digits after decimal.

[See the docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_series_equal.html)

Not good to use asserts but if you want to avoid numpy, this is a way.

Comment: Since `check_less_precise` has been deprecated since 1.1.0, it is now recommended to use `rtol` and `atol` instead. [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_series_equal.html)