# How to check if 2 DataFrames are close? (not equal)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I'm looking for a function that compares 2 df using tolerance. for example:

```
df1.a = [1,2]
df2.a = [2,2]
```

I would like to define tolerance = 2
and receive output such that 
`compare_df_func(df1,df2, tolerance = 2)` is True. 
pd.equals doesn't have a tolerance feature and merge as well.
I thought of using merge with indicator = True so that I can see which rows exist only on each df, but it doesn't have a tolerance feature.
merge_asof does have but tolerance but it is implemented only for left merge and I'm looking for an outer merge.

I could use Numpy 'isclose' function per each column but I was hoping to find a pandas function/ efficient comparison between full df. 
what would you recommand?

Answer (score 0):

Original answer:

```py
np.all(np.isclose(df1.as_matrix(),df2.as_matrix(),atol=1))
```

Actually `pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix()` has been [depracated since version 0.23.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html).
It is recommended to use `.to_numpy()` instead ([see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html)).

```py
np.all(np.isclose(df1.to_numpy(), df2.to_numpy(), atol=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [np.allclose()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) to compare series. Shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554632/comparing-two-pandas-series-for-floating-point-near-equality) as well.

```
s1 = pd.Series([1,2])
s2 = pd.Series([2,2])
np.allclose(s1, s2, atol=1)
>> True
```