# What normalization means in value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, normalization

The question is not about coding but to understand what normalize means in terms of statistics and correlation of data
This is an example of what I am doing.
Without normalization:

```
plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(df['alcoholism'].value_counts(), marker='o')
plt.plot(df.query('no_show =="Yes"')['alcoholism'].value_counts(), color='black')
plt.show();
```

[image: without normalization]

With normalization:

```
plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(df['alcoholism'].value_counts(normalize=True), marker='o')
plt.plot(df.query('no_show =="Yes"')['alcoholism'].value_counts(normalize=True), color='black')
plt.show();
```

[image: with normalization]

Which one better correlates the values with or without normalization? or is it a whole wrong idea?
I am new to data and pandas, so excuse my bad code, chaining, commenting, style :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see when you normalize (second plot), the sum of both points is equal to 1, for each line that is plotted. Normalizing is giving you the *rate* of occurrences of each value instead of the *number* of occurrences.

Heres what [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) says:

> **normalize : bool, default False**
>     Return proportions rather than frequencies.

- `value_counts()` probably returns something like:

  ```
  0    110000
  1      1000
  dtype: int64
  ```
- and `value_counts(normalize=True)` probably returns something like:

  ```
  0    0.990991
  1    0.009009
  dtype: float64
  ```

In other words, the relation between the normalized and non-normalized can be checked as:

```
>>> counts = df['alcoholism'].value_counts()
>>> rate = df['alcoholism'].value_counts(normalize=True)
>>> np.allclose(rate, counts / counts.sum())
True
```

Where [`np.allclose`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554632/comparing-two-pandas-series-for-floating-point-near-equality#46555047) allowing to properly compare two series of floating point numbers.

Comment: So I have different figures that obscure the true rate of change and by using normalization I get approximation of the rate to see if both factors change at the same rate or not.
Is my explanation now correct?

Comment: Yes indeed @GauntletZoom. But also your first figure has more information as it allows to compare  the different group sizes `no_show=Yes` vs all patients. If this answsers your question, see [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)